# how to fix ts2322 issue in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When the state value is delivered to the sub-component, ts2322 era comes out. How do I fix it?

It's not a problem when transferring a function, but it's a problem when transferring a state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardUI from "./DashboardMain.presenter";
import axios from "axios";

const DashboardContainer = () => {
  const request = "http://localhost:4000/requests";

  // interface Iprops {
  //   id: number;
  //   title: string;
  //   client: string;
  //   due: string;
  //   count: number;
  //   amount: number;
  //   method: string[];
  //   material: string[];
  //   status: string;
  // }

  const [renderData, setRenderData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response: any = await axios.get(request);
      console.log(response);
      setRenderData(response.data);
      console.log(renderData);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return <DashboardUI renderData={renderData} />;
};
```

There is a problem in this area.

[image]

Comment: what's the complete error?

Comment: Did you define the props for `DashboadUI` component? Add its code to the question

Comment: Defined the type of `useState` like `useState<T>()`. replace `T` with renderData type.

Comment: I didn't define it. I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem because the state is initially initialized to undefined

It seems that TypeScript checks for errors because the state has a undefined value before data fetching is finished.

1. Check renderData to render

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardUI from "./DashboardMain.presenter";
import axios from "axios";

const DashboardContainer = () => {
  const request = "http://localhost:4000/requests";

  // interface Iprops {
  //   id: number;
  //   title: string;
  //   client: string;
  //   due: string;
  //   count: number;
  //   amount: number;
  //   method: string[];
  //   material: string[];
  //   status: string;
  // }

  const [renderData, setRenderData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response: any = await axios.get(request);
      console.log(response);
      setRenderData(response.data);
      console.log(renderData);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
  if(!renderData) return null

  return <DashboardUI renderData={renderData} />;
};
```

2. use down casting

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardUI from "./DashboardMain.presenter";
import axios from "axios";

const DashboardContainer = () => {
  const request = "http://localhost:4000/requests";

  // interface Iprops {
  //   id: number;
  //   title: string;
  //   client: string;
  //   due: string;
  //   count: number;
  //   amount: number;
  //   method: string[];
  //   material: string[];
  //   status: string;
  // }

  const [renderData, setRenderData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response: any = await axios.get(request);
      console.log(response);
      setRenderData(response.data);
      console.log(renderData);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return <DashboardUI renderData={renderData as Iprops} />;
};
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your component is functional component then you can pass the Type to it like below:

```
const YourComponent: React.FC<React.HTMLProps<Element>> = (props => {---your component code---})
```